# Is it ethical to be sleep deprived while working as a software developer (in a non-safety-critical environment)?

Tags: ethics, work-life-balance, work-life

Hypothetically: assume that someone is working as a software developer (on projects outside fields like medicine where software correctness is very important).

Is it ethical to be sleep deprived when working?

Please assume someone is still able to do something which count as work during working hours.

Let's also assume that company does not have a clear policy on this.

Comment: What is causing the sleep deprivation? Is the employer requiring 20-hour shifts from the employee, or is the employee showing up to work sleep-deprived due to their own outside activities and/or medical conditions?

Comment: The employee is showing up to work sleep-deprived due to their own outside activities.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I am not working right now. I usually sleep 9-10 hours during a night. When I was working before it was very tiring to me to be 8 hours at work and get so much sleep at night. Additionally I was spending around 1 hour to commute.

Comment: Could people who down vote question explain their reason?
I am new to this site so it would be helpful for me.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere There was multiple issues why it was so tiring. One of the solution I considered was sleeping less, but I decided against it. Anyway I decided to ask question for future reference.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks about ethics, yet has no ethics specific details for the workplace. We can only answer questions based on workplace experience, workplace laws and regulations or other workplace related matters. Ethics are a matter of personal values and philosophy.

Comment: If you're tired even after sleeping 8 or 9 hours a night, you should probably go see a doctor, as you might have an undiagnosed sleeping or metabolic disorder, or other health issue.

Comment: I agree with @HorusKol, a medical doctor can run tests on your blood, ask you relevant questions about your diet and daily habits, refer you to a sleep laboratory (so you can be observed sleeping during the night), or refer you to a psychologist in case you're depressed. Before you go see that doctor, you may want to keep a sleep log/journal on your phone to give him some data to work with. There are a number of good apps for that purpose in the app stores.

Answer (score 6):

Forget ethics. Management doesn't concern itself with ethics, but with results.

A manager is not your parent. If you're going to bed too late. If you're drinking too much at night. Or if you're playing video games all night long. That manager can hardly control what you do during your off-hours. However, if your performance is subpar, your manager can give you a warning, tell you to go home for the day, and/or if your performance doesn't improve, potentially fire you.

In addition to that, it's possible that you're sleep-deprived because of some underlying medical condition. In which case, the employee would need to seek medical advice and ask for reasonable accommodations from his employer (if possible).

In either case, if an employee shows up exhausted and sleep-deprived, that employee has the moral obligation to stop working if he/she can't do that work safely anymore (let's say if that employee operates heavy machinery, or if that employee is a surgeon).

With software development, it is a little bit more tricky. If you need absolutely correct software because you're working on medical software, you can not rely on a single individual anyway. You need multiple people to review every single line of code. You need multiple people to review the tests. There is basically a ton of work that goes into cross-checking everything. So working when sleep-deprived on medical software is less of a safety issue because of all the redundancies.

But it could still be a performance issue. And in that regard, it's management's job to get rid of employees that are not performing well or that are making too many costly mistakes.

Comment: So if management is happy with results and performence there is no performance issue?

Comment: @JanKowalski, Assuming it's not harming anyone, the answer is "yes". Now, I suppose the coworkers might be annoyed. If the coworkers are annoyed. Then, management may want to intervene.

Comment: Also, some companies like Google (or companies in South Korea) have sleeping pods for their employees, should they want to take naps in the middle of the day.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk In my previous workplace (Amazon in Poland) there also are sleeping pods.

Comment: Correctness in critical software is enforced with more means than just employees being in a good condition. The same should happen to some degree with all software. There is obviously a point of tiredness where staying at home in bed would be more effective than going to work.

Answer (score 2):

Being sleep deprived is not a moral issue.

Either the person who is sleep deprived is facing something extremely unfortunate in his/her life (or there's a valid cause), or is being an irresponsible adult.

If it's the former, he/she is not to blame for the fact that he/she is sleep deprived. Although, in such a case it would be better to take time off anyway. If no time off is available, then that person has a choice to make.

On the other hand, if the sleep deprived person is only so due his/her own negligence and irresponsible behavior, he/she is to blame for it. From the point of view of the requirement of being respectful of the job he/she has and to others in the organization and his/her own life, he/she has a responsibility.

You could say that such a person is morally questionable on these grounds, but that person may be so because "he/she can't help it." He/she doesn't mean to be disrespectful, and has even tried to change; it just seems difficult. In such a case, the irresponsible behavior may point to something deeper anyway.

All the same, being sleep deprived in itself is not morally questionable. The context in which it's happening and how it's being handled are the really important questions.

Maybe this question needs to be rephrased and put on [Psychology SE](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/) or [Philosophy SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/)?

All of this is assuming we  are talking of mentally able and healthy adults. My response is only limited to this set since the OP didn't state otherwise.

---

**EDIT**

To address the first comment by the OP, in that case, the person has a larger issue with who he/she is as a person. I personally may not immediately write it off as an ethics issue, but more of as a personality issue. It depends on many things.

Is the person doing it on purpose to spite a coworker or manager? Is the person doing it with the malicious intent of harming the organization or framing someone? Is the person facing a genuine problem at work and honestly, truly feels this is the best way to handle it? Without more information and insight I would forfeit making conclusions in favor of further examination.

To address the second comment, consider this. If a person is sleep deprived at work due to negligence (which is just irresponsible for the sake of being irresponsible), it shows he/she doesn't care of the consequences which will follow from this. Especially considering that this is for a delicate and mission critical role, through his/her actions the person is saying "It doesn't matter to me. If I make mistakes or can't perform so be it. Who cares? And if someone has to clean up my mess or make up for my mistakes or lack of contribution, it's their problem not mine. If the organization suffers because of this, or jobs are lost, oh well." And as we all know, actions speak louder than words.

Comment: I stated this question incorrectly. I wanted to ask if it is ethical that employee is sleep deprived due to conscious behavior and does not plan to change it.

Comment: Could you add argument why being sleep deprived due to negligence show disrespect of the job and others in the organization?

Comment: @JanKowalski Hi Jan, I've posted an update to my answer under "Edit." Hope it helps.

Comment: What makes it irresponsible if it's not a moral issue? I.e. I think the remainder of your answer does not warrant the main statement that it is not a moral issue.

Comment: @FrankHopkins "All the same, being sleep deprived in itself is not morally questionable. The context in which it's happening and how it's being handled are the really important questions."